# Why is MVC Web Api only reachable when started in debug mode?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, asp.net-web-api

I am facing a strange problem on both my laptop and desktop computer.

In my solution I have an MVC 4 Web Api and the solution is started by Visual Studio 2013.
So If set the Web API project as startup project then When I type some url of the web api it hits the controller.

But if the startup folder is another project, like a website that consumes this web api, then the web api is just unreachable.

I even tried to hit the same url that works when web api is started in debug mode.

So, what could be wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found the actual problem.
I am running Windows 7 x64 and Visual Studio 2013. 
I had to uncheck the Enable Edit and Continue checkbox under Tools->Options->Debugging.

Now I am using a single startup project in my solution and I can call the web api also when not in Debug mode.

Answer (score 1):

Most likely the issue is that web server is not running. Try hosting your web API in IIS with a fixed URL and port.

Or your try setting multiple start up projects like this:

- In your Solution Explorer,
- Select, Right click your solution.
- On the Project menu, click Properties. The Solution Property Pages dialog box opens.
- click `Startup Project`.
- Click `Multiple Startup Projects` and set the project actions start.

[image]

Comment: The Web Api is hosted in IIS Express.

Comment: I have used a empty project template for creating the ASP.NET Web API. For some reason when starting in release mode it's just not hosted in IIS Expres. By adding it to the Multiple startup project the issue was solved.   I have noticed the same problem with MVC 5 and Empty Web API project under Visual Studio 2013. My problem is solved now. Thank you Dalorzo!

Answer (score 0):

Two possible ideas to try:

1. Left click on the WebApi project, and open the properties window (F4 for shortcut key) ensure `Always Start When Debugging` is set to `true`
2. When debugging your consumer application, right click on the WebApi Project, and click `Debug > Start New Instance`

If they don't work the best solution would be to host the WebApi application using IIS / IISExpress